# First steps to isolate leak?

Tags: plumbing, water, drywall, ceiling, leaks

I noticed that there's moisture creeping along a drywall seam in the ceiling in my living room.  The spot is cold and feels damp.   Our laundry room is in a bathroom right above, but the washer is in a drain pan that seems to be dry.

Should I cut away a piece of the drywall to inspect the source of the leak, or is there something else I can do to find out more information?

Similar questions mostly relate to roof leaking or water in the attic, which is not the same in this case, so I've posted a separate question.

[image: Image attached.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cutting away the drywall is one possible first step, with other possibilities being to see what is above the ceiling, depending on ability to access.  That section of drywall will definitely need to be removed anyway.  (both to repair, and to check for mold).  Finding the source can be difficult because the source of the water might not be directly above.  Water can run along various boards to find a low place to settle.  It could start at some point on an outside wall and go a fair distance horizontal.